# jackson object mapper is not resolvable to a concrete type

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jackson, glassfish, payara

I have a problem trying to setup jakarta ee 9 to use jackson through Feature interface (or any other method that I tried). After about 8h I finnaly found a warning that tries to tell me something, but I have no idea how to solve it:

```
[2022-05-10T20:48:17.916+0200] [Payara 5.2022.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors] [tid: _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1652208497916] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.Class<?>> from public void com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.setMixInAnnotations(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.Class<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker<?> from public void com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.setVisibilityChecker(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker<?>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
]]
```

My Feature:

```java
@Provider
public class JsonFeature implements Feature {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper =
            new ObjectMapper(){{
                configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, false);
                configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
                configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
                configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
                configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
                configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
            }};
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        System.out.println("#############################################");
        System.out.println("JsonFeature.configure()");
        System.out.println("#############################################");

        context.property("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);
        context.register(mapper);
        // also tried:
        // context.register(JacksonFeature.class);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I am registering my app by extending class with Application, and no config inside:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
    public class KICApplication extends Application {
}
```

relevant pom fragment:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <!-- ############### jakarta ############### -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
```

App is deployed on Payara 5.2022.1. I am also using Hibernate, but I don't think it's relevant.

after some time I think I mananaged to technically load it, because I can see sout in logs, but no warnings. But I don't think it's used, bencause I can't send nested json to endpoint:
AccountDto:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AccountDto {

    @NotNull
    private String login;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String surname;
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    // na późniejszą wersję (na innym branchy)
    // @NotNull
    private String phoneNumber;

    private Long version;

    private ArrayList<AccessLevelDto> accessLevels;
}
```

AccessLevelDto

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "level"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DataAdministratorDto.class, name = DataAdministrator.LEVEL_NAME),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DataClientDto.class, name = DataClient.LEVEL_NAME),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DataSpecialistDto.class, name = DataSpecialist.LEVEL_NAME)
})
public abstract class AccessLevelDto {

    private String level;

}
```

DataClient/SpecialistDto

```
@Data
public class DataClientDto extends AccessLevelDto {
}
```

DataAdministratorDto

```
@Data
public class DataAdministratorDto extends AccessLevelDto {

    private String test;
}
```

JSON i try to send to endpoint:

```
{
    "login": "login-xD",
    "firstName": "imie",
    "surname": "nazwisko",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "phoneNumber": "123123123",
    "version": 123,
    "accessLevels": [
        {
            "level": "ADMINISTRATOR",
            "test": "lol"
        },
        {
            "level": "SPECIALIST"
        }
    ]
}
```

deserializing it with ObjectMapper.readValue() works fine, so it must be the problem that jackson is not properly registered

Also the error on sending the json to endpoint

```
[2022-05-10T21:26:51.825+0200] [Payara 5.2022.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller] [tid: _ThreadID=82 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1652210811825] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Unable to deserialize property 'accessLevels' because of: Can't create instance]]

[2022-05-10T21:26:51.840+0200] [Payara 5.2022.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=82 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1652210811840] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[pl.lodz.p.it.ssbd2022.ssbd03.KICApplication]: Servlet.service() for servlet pl.lodz.p.it.ssbd2022.ssbd03.KICApplication threw exception
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ReflectionUtils.createNoArgConstructorInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.getInstance(ObjectDeserializer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionDeserializer.deserializeNext(CollectionDeserializer.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.deserializeNext(ObjectDeserializer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:212)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1072)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:885)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:50)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1637)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:581)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
]]
```

Comment: This could be unrelated to the problem, but Payara will use another version of Jackson than the one you provided in your pom.xml, it uses 2.12.4: https://search.maven.org/artifact/fish.payara.api/payara-bom/5.2022.1/pom